# shredding xml file with xmltable db2

Tags: db2, xmltable

Its possibile give input at XMLTable  xml file store in my desktop pc?
How ?

```
select id, name, T.*
```

`INSERT INTO abc(name)
SELECT  x.name
from XMLTABLE('$i/product' PASSING CAST(? AS XML) as "i"
    COLUMNS
      name  VARCHAR(10) PATH 'name',
)    as x;`

How pass my file store on the desktop in my pc?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL statements can't access files outside of the database manager.  To load data in an XML file and write it to a table, you'd either need to use a database utility (like `LOAD` or `IMPORT`), or write your own program to read the data from files on the client machine (i.e., your PC) and perform the inserts.